# Point to Lightsail Loadbalancer without changing Nameservers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I have site hosted on Lightsail and I am going to be using the Lightsail Load-Balancer. How do I point the DNS records to the Loadbalancer without changing my name servers to AWS? All Lightsail documentation says is to create a DNS zone in Lightsail and change name servers. The Load Balancer endpoint is not an IP Address.

Is there a way to do this or is the only way changing name servers? I have to pay to change name servers so I would like to know if there is any way to point to the LB with my current DNS provider. If changing is the only option, I would much rather opt for Route 53 than changing it to Lightsail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lightsail console you will be provided with a DNS name for your load balancer as shown below.

[image]

This CNAME record can be used within any DNS configuration, there is no need to change your name servers assuming the functionality your provider offers supports your usecase.

If you're adding the load balancer as a subdomain record e.g. `foo.example.com` any DNS provider should allow you to add a new CNAME record for your subdomain. Simply paste the DNS value in your CNAME value and the record will resolve.

If you're adding the load balancer on the apex record (root domain) e.g. `example.com` then you will need to use a DNS provider that supports the functionality of either `Alias` records or in some cases an `ANAME` record. If your provider does then you can use this type of record and enter the value of the load balancer name, otherwise you will need to switch to a DNS configuration that supports this functionality (which Route 53 does).

If you decide to use Route 53 instead the documentation can be found here.

Comment: I added a cname for www which points to the DNS name of the LB and I also added the SSL certificate. But going to www.domain.com gives be a 'too many redirects error' and the dig command points to the DNS name and two other IP address which seem to be for EC2 compute instances

Comment: Your application is redirecting presumably because it wants to be on the load balancer domain. Which type of application are you using on your lightsail instance

Comment: I have a Laravel application on LAMP bitnami stack but the database is separate